# Cumulative sum by bins in obiee

Tags: obiee

I want to generate a report in obiee , by grouping countries and showing there cumulative sum

I tried creating bins like for china I created a bin which contains singapore, taiwan and china. another bin for japan containing some countries. using pivot table i can show the sum of customers in a region by dates for these two bins. but when I need a cumulative sum for every bin it is giving weird values

Number of employee by region and date where china and japan are bins

```
           china  japan
```

01-Nov-18       1  3

02-Nov-18       2         4

03-Nov-18       1   1

04-Nov-18   2   5

05-Nov-18   4   7

06-Nov-18   5   7

where as result i want( how can I achieve this)

```
     China    Japan
```

01-Nov-18   1   3

02-Nov-18   3   7

03-Nov-18   4   8

04-Nov-18   6   13

05-Nov-18   10  20

06-Nov-18   15  27

Answer (score 0):

The measure has to be a running sum in that case. RSUM(YourMeasure)

Answer (score 0):

Make a duplicate layer of the measure column. Click on the duplicated column and select the option 'Display as Running Sum'.